# Python Web Scraping login with captcha

Tags: python, session, beautifulsoup, python-requests, captcha

I have to log-in on a web page using web scraping, but it requires to solve a captcha as well. I am able to solve the captcha. I am having problem persisting session.

```
session = requests.Session()
html = session.get(url).content
soup = bs(html, 'html.parser')
name = soup.find('input', attrs={'id':some_id1})
pass = soup.find('input', attrs={'id':some_id2})
captcha = soup.find('input', attrs={'id':some_id3})
```

After this I solve the captcha.

```
credentials = {
        some_id1 : username,
        some_id2 : password,
        some_id3 : captchatext,
    }
```

I don't know how to proceed further with the sessions, I came up with the below code but it does not work. I have also looked for various answers but none of them works.

```
session.post(url, data=credentials)
response = session.get(url).content
soup2 = bs(response, 'html.parser')
```

I need to fetch data from a URL which opens up after a successful log-in.

Answer (score 0):

Use dev tools of your browser to inspect the requests done on that specific url. You will find a request url which you have to pass in the post method along with the payload i.e. Credentials. Then you will get correct response.